# How to achieve specific css flexbox layout with multiple columns of different row items

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve the flex layout as per the image below. In my code examples, I've not been successful, yet so I can't provide any useful code snippets.

- Box 1 would be **fixed width** and **100% height**
- Box 2 and 3 would be **50% height** and **100% width**
- Box 4 would be **fixed width** and **100% height**

It would be wrapped in a container DIV (not shown).

Is this correct usage for Flex, or should a grid be used for something like this? I've found an example that manages to get either box 1 or box 4 in position (such as here: [Mozilla Flex Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Mastering_Wrapping_of_Flex_Items), but not with both.

[image]

Comment: Make a div that contains box 2 and 3 and set `flex-grow: 1` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with flexbox - you will need a container div for box 2 and box 3. You can use something like this:

```css
#layout {
  display: flex;
  resize: both;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#box1, #box4 {
  width: 100px;
}

#box2-3 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#box2, #box3 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#box1, #box2, #box3, #box4 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="layout">
  <div id="box1">Box 1</div>
  <div id="box2-3">
    <div id="box2">Box 2</div>
    <div id="box3">Box 3</div>
  </div>
  <div id="box4">Box 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For layouts with such requirements [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) is a much better choice than Flexbox.

> CSS Grid Layout excels at dividing a page into major regions or defining the relationship in terms of size, position, and layer, between parts of a control built from HTML primitives.

Here's a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/nevnein/pen/GRJmqwp). You can modify the fixed columns width by changing the `grid-template-columns` definitions.

Comment: Appreciate the recommendation. I haven't actually used CSS Grid before but will take a look at how it works.